# How can I use .charCodeAt on an array?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can use the apply method, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use it, namely what goes into the parenthesis. I've tried reading articles on it and even watching some YT videos, but end up still feeling confused.

What I'm trying to do here is to convert the following string into unicode by using charCodeAt, then I have to add 13 to each value because I'm using the ROT13 cipher. After that I plan to use fromCharCode to return the numerical values into letters to get a message, and then use .join to get the full message.

```
function rot13(str) {

  var strSplit = str.split('');
  strSplit.charCodeAt.apply();

}


rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Comment: you can try `String.prototype.charCodeAt(arr, index);`

Comment: It's probably worth noting that simple adding 13 to the charCode is not sufficient for a rotation cipher, since it doesn't do any rotation

Answer (score 1):

Use array functions:

```
function rot13(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split('');
  var res = strSplit.map(l => l.charCodeAt())
  return res;
}


console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

You may want to concat the numbers together as a string:

```
console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC").map(l => JSON.stringify(l)).join(""))
```

However, this may have some caveats...

Answer (score 0):

**Array** doesn't have `charCodeAt` method.

You can iterate through all the characters after doing split

Try this

```js
function rot13(str) 
{
  return str.split('').map(function(item) {
    return String.fromCharCode(item.charCodeAt(0) + 13)
  }).join("")
}

console.log( rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC") );
```

More generic

```js
function rot(str, num) 
{
  return str.split('').map(function(item) {
    return String.fromCharCode(item.charCodeAt(0) + num)
  }).join("")
}

console.log( rot("SERR PBQR PNZC", 13) );
```